# Setting up a build definition where the source relies on third party assemblies?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, tfsbuild

My structure for TFS is such:

```
{Main TFS Project}
     3rd Party Assemblies
     Development
          Source
     Integration
          Source
```

I am using continuous integration for my development build, but currently I have to setup the working folder so that I am pointing to: {Main TFS Project} root folder.  This is not ideal, because any check-in to the system kicks off my Development continuous build. I don't want to have the 3rd party assemblies in each branch, because they are shared throughout projects. What are other users doing?

**Update**
Before I wrote this message I had tried what kroonwijk had suggested, but my build still fails. this is what my work folders section looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the build definition, you have the ability to specify multiple folders to be downloaded to the build system when the build starts. From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190721.aspx:

> When you create your build definition, on the Workspace tab, you
>   specify the folders that contain the files that you want to download
>   and how these folders should be mapped to local folders on the build
>   agent.

So just specify your 3rd Party Assemblies folder together with the Subproject folder you want to build in the Workspaces tab of your build definition, and only those folders will be checked and build.

Comment: I tried that, but my build is still failing. I updated my question with an image.

Comment: Please specify how your build fails, which messages do you get? And of course you need to make sure that the 3rd Party Assemblies are at the same relative location on your build system as that you use them locally on your development system. And the project file should use relative paths to find the 3rd party assemblies.

Comment: Well, it worked! It turns out I had to specify the actual source folder for the Build Agent folder.  So the $/et alia PIM/Development/Trunk/Source  needed to have the $(SourceDir)\Development\Trunk\Source specified rather than the root. Like you said, It had to be relative to the 3rd party Assembly folder. Thanks you!